# Beautifulsoup Text from Table using same Span tag

Tags: python, html, html-table, beautifulsoup

When using beautifulsoup to extract text from a table, I am unable to extract text because of multiple text in same .

I used the following codes -

```
results = soup.find_all('span', class_="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold")
results[0]
```

I get the following results

```
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold">
LATCH connections
<span class="product-model-tooltip">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="crux-icons crux-icons-help-information"></span>
<span class="product-model-tooltip-window">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="crux-icons crux-icons-close"></span>
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold">LATCH connections</span>
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small">Type of LATCH connection.
</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
```

Then I tried to get the text

```
results[0].get_text()
```

gives me

```
'\nLATCH connections\n\n\n\n\nLATCH connections\nType of LATCH connection.\n\n\n\n'
```

Then I used

```
results[0].get_text().replace('\n', '')
```

and I get

```
'LATCH connectionsLATCH connectionsType of LATCH connection.'
```

All I need is 'LATCH connections' and 'Type of LATCH connection' as two columns.

Can you please help.

Comment: Are you trying to get   results[0]=''LATCH connectionsLATCH connections"   and   results[1]="Type of LATCH connection"  ? If so you can probably split it using regex.

Comment: I have separate them out. results[0] is what I posted as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are many ways to do that.  One way is :

After you find by class, you need to find by same class name again like following

```
parent_span= soup.find('span', class_="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold")
result = parent_span.find('span', class_="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold")
print(result.text)
```

if you want to pick only one tag, you don't need to use `find_all`. Just use `find`.

Comment: it worked and I get 'Latch Connection' . However I ran the query on all results and I got only the result[0] of the table. Is there any reason?

Comment: I getting only the first value. is it because of /n tags? Is there work around?

Comment: the `find` gets first value.  so it is same with `results = find_all()` and results[0]

Comment: If my answer was helpful for you, could you upvote me? :)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556113/beautiful-soup-multiple-span-extract-table) is exactly what I am looking for. I need all the values in the span and not the first item