# Beautiful soup multiple Span Extract Table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on my class assignment. I have to extract the data from the SPECS table from this webpage.

https://www.consumerreports.org/products/drip-coffee-maker/behmor-connected-alexa-enabled-temperature-control-396982/overview/

The data I need is stored as

```
<h2 class="crux-product-title">Specs</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="product-model-features-specs-item">
<div class="row">
<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-model-features-specs-item-key'>
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold">
Programmable
<span class="product-model-tooltip">
<span class="crux-icons crux-icons-help-information" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="product-model-tooltip-window">
<span class="crux-icons crux-icons-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold">Programmable</span>
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small">Programmable models have a clock and can be set to brew at a specified time.</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-model-features-specs-item-value">
<span class='crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small'>Yes</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="product-model-features-specs-item">
<div class="row">
<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-model-features-specs-item-key'>
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold">
Thermal carafe/mug
<span class="product-model-tooltip">
<span class="crux-icons crux-icons-help-information" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="product-model-tooltip-window">
<span class="crux-icons crux-icons-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold">Thermal carafe/mug</span>
<span class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small">Keeps coffee warm for about four hours; thermal mugs don&#039;t hold heat as well.</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
```

I need to create Lists for the three span class

```
class="crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold
crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small
crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small
```

**The problem with extracting the table is because of multiple span used in the table.**

**I used BEAUTIFUL SOUP and used *find_all* and *find* and used the span name to call it.**

**I always got the first value.**

How do I do this?

Comment: Can we see your code so far?  Usually you're going to have to specify an index if you have a list of elements myelements[2] for example.

Comment: 'url = "https://www.consumerreports.org/products/drip-coffee-maker/behmor-connected-alexa-enabled-temperature-control-396982/overview/"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
table = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small"})
print(table)'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = ''' ''' # Your html
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
spans = doc.selects('span.crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold')
for span in spans:
    # print (span.firstText())
    print (span.select('span.crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small--bold').text)
    print (span.select('span.crux-body-copy crux-body-copy--small').unescape())
```

Result:

```
Programmable
Programmable models have a clock and can be set to brew at a specified time.
Thermal carafe/mug
Keeps coffee warm for about four hours; thermal mugs don't hold heat as well.
```